# Startup time of an angular dart application

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Runnig different tutorial code of AngularDart I measured on average ~1 min startup time with just Dartium as target. This is a significant show stopper for the adoption of AngularDart as the development time will increase significantly. How can the start up time be reduced and the development cycle trimmed?

Comment: Are you counting the initial first-time preparation, or the time it takes once running to incrementally compile?  As in, are you aware that you can make incremental changes while Dartium is "live" (via pub serve) and those changes are almost immediately available?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for the hint, I was not aware of the incremental compile. Will test it. Is the experience of you and GünterZöchbauer that you can work as fast with AngularDart as with AngularJS?

Comment: I never worked with AngularJS, so I can't possibly answer. :)